# In simple pendulum problem, how to change Initial boundary conditions polar into cartesian coordinate

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

The problem is

Using the equations of motion for the simple pendulum in cartesian coordinates (Eq.(3.7)), numarically integrate the trajectory for the initial conditions

```
(θ[0], θ'[0]) = (0.1, 0)
```

Plot the pendulum angle `theta[t]` and the pendulum length `l[t]=sqrt[x[t]^2+y[t]^2]` as a function of time.

The equation (3.7) is

```
x''[t] == (-x[t] x'[t]^2 - x[t] y'[t]^2 + x[t] y[t] g)/l[t]^2
y''[t] == (-y[t] x'[t]^2 - y[t] y'[t]^2 - x[t]^2 g)/l[t]^2
```

At first i try to make EOM(equation of motion) only express for `x[t]` and `y[t]`. So use `l[t]=sqrt[x[t]^2+y[t]^2]]`. And in this problem the initial boundary condition expressed polar coordinate, sine I try to change IBC(Initial Boundary Condition) as

```
θ[t] == ArcTan[y[t]/x[t]]; 
Tan[θ[t]] == Sin[θ[t]]/Cos[θ[t]] == y[t]/x[t]
```

Since,

```
y[0]=Sin[θ[0]]
x[0]=Cos[θ[0]]
```

Actually I don't know that another two IBC correctly.

there is my process by using Mathematica and solutions what I want to plot. Actually I just try to make to plot similarly to solution. So I was assumed the one of IBC.

[image]

That is, I want to know method of changing IBC, and I want to plot the graph in solution.

Comment: Share the pdf file which contains the equations and other related stuff.

Comment: Reading your question couple of times, I still didn't know what exactly you want? Do you want to know that why the MMA results are not the same for ll vs tt as shown in the pdf?